# How to combine nodes in a subtree with one child?

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp, nested-lists

I have a tree as a nested list:

```
(A (B (C (D word) (E word))) (F (G word)))
```

and I want to combine nodes when the subtree has one child in format Parent+Child so the result is:

```
(A (B+C (D word) (E word)) (F+G word))
```

I am currently using a recursive function to process the tree. I have tried

```
(defun my-func (tree)

  (cond
    ; base case
    ((null tree) nil)
    ; subtree has one child
    ((and (atom (car tree)) (listp (car(cdr tree))) (= (length (cdr tree)) 1))
      (my-func (cdr tree)))
    ; first element is atom
    ((atom (car tree)) (cons (car tree) (my-func (cdr tree))))
    ; else
    (t (cons (my-func (car tree)) (my-func (cdr tree)))))
)
```

My input is : `("A" ("B" ("C" ("D" "word1") ("E" "word2"))) ("F" ("G" "word3")))`

Output is: `("A" (("C" ("D" "word1") ("E" "word2"))) (("G" "word3")))`

I am getting close but my questions are now:

Why am I getting extra parentheses around sublists `(("C" ("D" "word1") ("E" "word2")))` and `(("G" "word3"))` ?

Also, I am still struggling with getting the notation "Parent+Child"

Comment: The expressions you show in your question don't amount to a recursive function.

Comment: Tip: write your code so it returns a whole new object (entire tree) which has the transformations that you want, compared to the old object. Do not mutate a single cell (i.e. do not replace the value of any `car` or `cdr`).  Mutation of cons cell structure is a good way to give yourself problems that will have you pulling out your hair. Even if you debug it, you're then still left with a function that destroys the integrity of its input, which makes it harder to use.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I edited my code to show the full function. So I tried to adopt your tips by recursing down the tree and building the list with cons on the way up. Is this what you mean by returning a new object instead of doing (setf (car tree) value) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so first of all, it's 1970 already and we have invented the notion of using abstraction.  Rather than code which is full of `car`, `cdr` & `cons` we can use meaningful names for our objects: We'll deal with objects called *nodes* where each node is either a *tree* or a *leaf*.  A tree has a name and a list of branches (branch lists are lists, there's no need for abstraction there), leaves have no defined structure: they're just not trees.

```
(defun node-tree-p (o)
  (consp o))

(defun node-leaf-p (o)
  (not (node-tree-p o)))

(defun tree-name (tree)
  (car tree))

(defun tree-branches (tree)
  (cdr tree))

(defun make-tree (name branches)
  (cons name branches))
```

I'm going to represent coalesced tree names explicitly as lists (so, in particular, they are *lists*, so it's OK to use list functions on them, we don't need to abstract them).  So we'll need a function to coalesce names which wraps the fiddlyness in doing so depending on whether one is already a listy name:

```
(defun coalesce-names (n1 n2)
  (append (if (listp n1) n1 (list n1))
          (if (listp n2) n2 (list n2))))
```

So now we can write a function which walks over a tree and coalesces what is coalescable:

```
(defun maybe-coalesce-node (node)
  (if (node-tree-p node)
      ;; it's a tree, which is a candidate
      (if (= (length (tree-branches node)) 1)
          ;; it's got one branch: it's a good candidate
          (let ((branch (first (tree-branches node))))
            (if (node-tree-p branch)
                ;; the branch is a tree: this is coalescable: coalesce
                ;; it and then recurse on the result
                (maybe-coalesce-node (make-tree (coalesce-names (tree-name node)
                                                                (tree-name branch))
                                                (tree-branches branch)))
              ;; the branch is a leaf: this is not coalescable
              node))
        ;; it's a tree, but it has more than one branch, so make a
        ;; tree whose branches have been coalesced
        (make-tree (tree-name node)
                   (mapcar #'maybe-coalesce-node (tree-branches node))))
    ;; it's a leaf, which is not a candidate
    node))
```

Note that this is a *function*: it takes a node as an argument and returns a node, which may be the same node, but it does not modify the node.

And now:

```
> (maybe-coalesce-node
   '(a (b 1) (c (d (e 2))) (f (g (h 3) (i 4)))))
(a (b 1) ((c d e) 2) ((f g) (h 3) (i 4)))
```

So, the result of this is that we can coalesce trees to make trees whose names are lists of names.  Now we want to turn those names into strings.  Well to do this let's write a general tree-mapper function, which will map a function over a node:

```
(defun map-node (f node)
  ;; map F over the nodes in TOP-NODE.  F should return a node, but it
  ;; may have a different structure than its argument.
  (let ((new-node (funcall f node)))
    (if (node-tree-p new-node)
        (make-tree (tree-name new-node)
                   (mapcar #'(lambda (n)
                               (map-node f n))
                           (tree-branches new-node)))
      new-node)))
```

And now let's write a function which rewrites a tree's name, using an auxiliary function to do the work:

```
(defun stringify-tree-name (name)
  (format nil "~{~A~^+~}" (if (listp name) name (list name))))

(defun maybe-rewrite-node-name (node &key (name-rewriter #'stringify-tree-name))
  (if (node-tree-p node)
      (make-tree (funcall name-rewriter (tree-name node))
                 (tree-branches node))
    node))
```

And now we can coalesce and rewrite the names of nodes:

```
> (map-node #'maybe-rewrite-node-name
                       (maybe-coalesce-node
                        '(a (b 1) (c (d (e 2))) (f (g (h 3) (i 4))))))
("a" ("b" 1) ("c+d+e" 2) ("f+g" ("h" 3) ("i" 4)))
```

---

As an exercise: rewrite `maybe-coalesce-node` in terms of `map-node`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! At lines 2 and 5 of the maybe-coalesce-node function, what is the function treep? Is it built-in or is it the same as the function you defined node-tree-p?

Comment: @grace9: yes, sorry, it should be `node-tree-p`: that function was originally called `treep` & I did not restart the Lisp to check my function worked with the new names.  Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

The extra parenthesis comes from calling `(my-func (cdr tree))` because at that point `(cadr tree)` is a list, so `(cdr tree)` will get you two parenthesis.
I am not sure what you mean by B+C. Let's assume you are returning it as a string "B+C", so we will use `format` to combine them.

```
(defun my-func (tree)
  (cond
    ; base case
    ((null tree) nil)
    ; subtree is an atom
    ((atom tree) tree)
    ; subtree has one 
    ((and (atom (car tree)) (listp (car(cdr tree))) (= (length (cdr tree)) 1))
      (cons (format nil "~a+~a" (car tree) (caadr tree)) (mapcar #'my-func (cdadr tree))) )
    ; first element is atom
    ((atom (car tree))
      (cons (car tree) (mapcar #'my-func (cdr tree))))
    ; else
    (t (cons (my-func (car tree)) (my-func (cdr tree)))))
)
```

You can also combine B+C as a list, so use `(list (car tree) '+ (caadr)) tree)` instead of `format`.